# Windows 10 executes everything as an Admin

Tags: windows-10

I noticed that my computer runs **everything** as an Admin by default,
I am aware that this is an major security issue and I already reenabled UAC and deleted all register entry's for run as admin @ `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

I am kindly and in despair asking for your help!

Comment: Did you restart your PC, also run from elevated cmd `sfc /scannow` and let that complete. Once done run, `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` from admin elevated cmd and let it complete. Reboot and then see afterwards if it's back to normal.

Comment: How do you know that the command you run really has administrator permissions when running?

Comment: thanks for the sharing! you can also check if the following method is helpful to you： https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/3-ways-to-enable-and-disable-built-in-administrator-in-windows-10.html

Answer (score 2):

`sfc /scannow`
and
`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`
Fixed my issue,

Thanks!! [Pimp Juice IT](https://superuser.com/users/510662/pimp-juice-it)

Not sure how to mark a comment as an awnser... sorry

Comment: You are welcome @DaveTheDave41...